# How to change the color of the tool bar in PyQt6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt6

using `self.toolBar.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")` only makes the icons on the toolbar red. How would I change the color of the toolbar too?
[toolbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E9Ll.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to fix it. Putting "border: none;" after setting the background color sets the whole tool bar's color instead of just the buttons.